# Automorphism group of complex manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemann-surfaces

The (holomorphic) automorphism group  of the unit disc is $SU(1,1)$ which is not a complex Lie group!

So why (intuitively) the (holomorphic) automorphism group of a complex manifold  wouldn't have
to be a complex Lie group even though if it is finite dimensional?

Comment: Why should each parameter appear holomorphically?

Comment: For instance because it has odd dimension?

Comment: A more reasonable question would be about classification of hermitian symmetric spaces whose automorphism groups are "naturally" complex Lie groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the automorphism group of a complex manifold $M$ is not always finite dimensional, the standard example is ${\mathbb C}^2$, its automorphism group contains the infinite-dimensional subgroups of "shears"
$$
(z,w)\mapsto (z, h(z)+w),
$$
where $h$ is an arbitrary entire function on ${\mathbb C}$. However, if $M$ is compact then indeed, $Aut(M)$ is *naturally* a real Lie group. Typically, though, the automorphism group is trivial.

Suppose you impose further assumptions on $M$, say, that it is a simply-connected [Hermitian symmetric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_symmetric_space#:%7E:text=Every%20Hermitian%20symmetric%20space%20is,spaces%20and%20a%20Euclidean%20space.&text=In%20this%20case%20the%20non,in%20the%20complex%20plane%20C.) (HSS). Two extreme cases of HSS's are:

1. Hermitian symmetric spaces of noncompact type. For instance, the open unit ball in ${\mathbb C}^n$.
2. Compact HSS. For instance, complex projective spaces.

As it turns out, in the second case, the automorphism group is *naturally* a complex Lie group, meaning that it has the structure of a complex Lie group $G$ such that the action map
$$
G\times M\to M 
$$
is holomorphic. Briefly, the space of holomorphic vector fields on $M$ is finite-dimensional (since $M$ is compact) and is **naturally a complex vector space** (that much is indeed clear and is true regardless of compactness, etc.). Each holomorphic vector field is integrable (again, by compactness), hence, you conclude that the identity component of $G$ is naturally a complex Lie group.

On the other hand, in the former case, the automorphism group is *never* naturally a complex Lie group. Here is a reason (hopefully, intuitive enough). As it turns out, each HSS of noncompact type is biholomorphic to a bounded domain $D$ in ${\mathbb C}^n$ and the stabilizer of a point $x\in D$ is a compact connected nontrivial Lie subgroup $K< G$. Now, if $G$ were to admit a complex structure such that its action on $D$ is holomorphic, then $K$ would be also a complex Lie subgroup of $G$. But then, for each point $y\in D$ the $K$-orbit
$$
Ky=\{k(y): k\in K\}
$$
would be a compact complex submanifold of $D$, hence, of ${\mathbb C}^n$. Thus, $Ky$ would be a single point (namely, $y$). It would then follow that $K$ is a trivial subgroup, which is a contradiction.